# How can I use fetch to post in a local json file?

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, fetch

I am trying to write a simple program that add new data to a local json file using fetch but whenever
I run the code it returns this error: POST 405 (Method Not Allowed). Is there something I am missing?

```
async function addUser() {

const response = await fetch("users.json", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Name 4"
    })
});

const data = await response.json();

console.log(data);  }
```

Comment: add code here instead of image.

Comment: U need a server to access file

Comment: How can I use that?

Comment: create server, using `express`.

Comment: We need some more context here. Where do you run de code on? Is users.json the local file you want to write to or is it the new data? Also is users.json hosted or is it a local file on your system?

Comment: users.json is the local file I want to write to and is a local file on my system.

Comment: You can't post data in a JSON file, you need to implement a POST route with express for example

Comment: Thank you guys for help I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply POST to the URL of a static file and expect the server to change it. (If you could update URLs by simply POSTing to them then Google's homepage would be defaced every few seconds and the WWW wouldn't have any useful content on it).

You need to write server-side code to process the POST request and store the data.

Typically this is done by storing the data in a *database* (which will protect you from such things as race conditions) and generating the JSON on demand (i.e. when a GET request is received).

Comment: Oh, ok, I think i undestand now. Thank you. So, basically, I can't use a json file like a small kind of database where I can add, delete data etc. (like txt files used in c++ with ifstream, ofstream).

Comment: @jjkasd — You *could* use a JSON file as a database, but a tool designed to be used as a database is much better for the job. Either way, you still need server-side code to save the POSTed data.

Comment: One last question: If I want, for exemple, to store the highscore of a simple game in a file can I do that without using a database or server-side code?

Comment: I said "You need to write server-side code to process the POST request and store the data" and "Either way, you still need server-side code to save the POSTed data.". That hasn't changed.